# raid1: how to synchronize harddisks (Debian 6)

Tags: linux, debian, hard-disk, raid, synchronization

My system is Linux/Debian 6, using GPT (GUID Partition Table).

If I run the command

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

I see the following situation:

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md3 : active raid1 sdb4[1]
      1822442815 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
      1073740664 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb1[1]
      33553336 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

How should I understand this?

Is sdb out of sync or sda?

What is [_U] meaning?

How can I synchronize the harddisks?

Following information may be helpful:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Aug 20 11:23:55 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 33553336 (32.00 GiB 34.36 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 33553336 (32.00 GiB 34.36 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Sep 25 21:50:55 2013
      State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

       Name : rescue:0
       UUID : 79ca4cbd:5d44fcad:01e8ed8e:0bd7009a
     Events : 22

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `sda` is not online. You can see this  from `/proc/mdstat` as `sda1` is not mentioned.

The last 2 lines of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` also point to that. They says that `/dev/sdb1` is active and `Number 0` removed (this was sda1).

First make sure `fdisk /dev/sda` works and has correct partition, then sync should be started automatic.

The `[_U]` means the second disc is unavailable and the first (number 1, sdb1) is there and ok. Which one is not available is unknown as the head of `/dev/sda1` is not found (and not set in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`?).

Comment: thank you I got it.. I've copied partition table to the new harddisk 

    `$ sgdisk -R /dev/sda /dev/sdb`   

and added them to the raid-array 

 `$ mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1
 $ mdadm /dev/md1 -a /dev/sda2
 $ mdadm /dev/md2 -a /dev/sda3
 $ mdadm /dev/md3 -a /dev/sda4` 

Now they are synchronizing: 

 `$ cat /proc/mdstat`